# Relacionamentos Aninhados

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Galera, estou com uma dúvida referente a relacionamento aninhado.

Quando meu código fica dessa forma:

```
 class CategoryListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'created_at']


class BookCreateListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    category = CategoryListSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'created_at', 'category']
```

Retorna assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando comento o `category = CategoryListSerializer()`

Ele retorna dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero entender do porque desse comportamento e como posso realizar POST dessa forma, pois quando insiro o category ele pede para sobrescrever o `.create()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão, os serializadores aninhados são somente leitura. Se você deseja oferecer suporte a operações de gravação em um campo serializador aninhado, precisará criar `create()` e/ou `update()` métodos para especificar explicitamente como os relacionamentos filhos devem ser salvos.

exemplo:

```
 class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album
```

Se o campo for usado para representar um relacionamento para muitos, você deverá adicionar o `many=True` ao campo do serializador.

exemplo:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```

Referencia: [https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/](http://https:/www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

Comment: Então, o mais estranho que quando faço dessa forma de sobrescrever, sou obrigado a criar uma categoria e o livro. Isso tem relação ao models?

Comment: Quando você cria uma relaçao aninhada por padrão ela é somente leitura, ou seja , você não precisa criar uma categoria sempre que criar um livro, apenas precisa associar uma categoria existente. 
Veja se você está passando o parametro (read_only=True),  igual os exemplos que deixei.

Comment: Acabei corrigindo o models, mesmo utilizando o read_only era solicitado para cadastrar a categoria.

Comment: sua solução só precisa de um pequeno ajuste, eu usaria o `get_or_create` uma vez que nem sempre eu preciso criar um `Track` ou `Album` , 
 por exemplo eu posso querer adicionar um track pra um album já existente ou vice versa [documentação Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)